# Update sql database using Lotusscript

Tags: sql, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I am trying to update rows of my database through lotusscript. My database connection working well. But the result.update command doesn't work and my rows aren't updated by the query. The problem is in the query result.updaterow because it doesn't make errors anywhere else.
Anyone have a solution to make it work;

```vb
Option Public
Option Declare



UseLSX "*LSXODBC"

Sub Initialize
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim dbcontacts As NotesDatabase

Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim DocContact As NotesDocument

Dim CandidatView As NotesView
Dim ContactView As NotesView

Dim connection As ODBCConnection


Dim query As ODBCQuery
Dim result As ODBCResultSet


Dim consultantref As String

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set connection = New ODBCConnection
Set dbcontacts= session.GetDatabase("", "names.nsf")


Set query = New ODBCQuery
Set result = New ODBCResultSet
Set query.Connection = connection
Set result.Query = query

On Error Resume Next

Set CandidatView=db.GetView( "Persons" )    
Set ContactView=dbcontacts.GetView( "(PersonsTestImport)" )

Call connection.ConnectTo("datasource", "username", "password")

If connection.IsConnected Then

    Set doc=CandidatView.GetFirstDocument
    CandidatView.AutoUpdate = False
    While Not ( doc Is Nothing )

        query.SQL="select * from users where id_toucan='"+doc.can_doc_ID(0)+"'"

         result.Execute

        If result.IsResultSetAvailable Then

            Do
                result.NextRow
                namepers=doc.can_pers(0)
                Set DocContact=ContactView.Getdocumentbykey(consultantref) 
                Call result.SetValue("first_name",DocContact.FirstName(0))
                Call result.SetValue("last_name", DocContact.LastName(0))       
                Call result.SetValue("email", DocContact.MailAddress(0))
                result.UpdateRow
            Loop Until result.IsEndOfData   
        End If

        Set doc = CandidatView.GetNextDocument( doc )
    Wend
Else

    MsgBox"Not connected"

End If
result.Close(DB_CLOSE)
connection.Disconnect

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to add a on error goto? to display the potential error that occurs?

Comment: see also http://www.johnbrown.com.au/approach/webfaq04902330.html

Comment: Yes, the agent turn in the domino server, And i didn't see Any error in the logs documents of the server . The agent works well to the end but doesn't update the selected rows

Comment: Where do you set consultantref?  Is DocContact a valid document at that point?

Comment: Yes , i use message boxes to see my 3 values And all of them are there. But the command result.updaterow doesn't do the job

Comment: The UpdateRow operation returns a value, but you are not catching it -  e.g.,, via status = result.UpdateRow.  You can pass that return code into connection.getErrorMessage.  See here for more info: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_UPDATEROW_METHOD.html Also here: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/00a7a1601df1d8f985256c54004e6d82?OpenDocument  And post the results.

Comment: In the code you posted I see "On Error Resume Next", thus it means you don't have error handling. Please post the code you use (with on error **goto**) or if it's really the code you use, update it: on error Goto ErrorHandle define a ErrorHandle: that print cstr(err) +" " + error$ (you should get this in the log.nsf or make msgbox.

Comment: i have this error with a result.GetErrorMessage command :  
LS:DO- Cannot access requested row. –

And this error with a result.GetExtendedErrorMessage command :  
LS:DO- The requested row doesn't exist, cannot be reached, is before the first or after the last row.

Comment: I don't know how UpdateRow tracks the relationship between the result set entries and actual table rows, but I'm wondering: does the primary key for the table include one of the fields that you are trying to update?

Comment: No, the primary key is not one of the fields that i want to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it with the sql query UPDATE and it's working now :

```
Option Public
Option Declare

UseLSX "*LSXODBC"

Sub Initialize
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim dbcontacts As NotesDatabase

Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim DocContact As NotesDocument

Dim CandidatView As NotesView
Dim ContactView As NotesView

Dim connection As ODBCConnection


Dim query As ODBCQuery
Dim result As ODBCResultSet


Dim consultantref As String

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set connection = New ODBCConnection
Set dbcontacts= session.GetDatabase("", "names.nsf")


Set query = New ODBCQuery
Set result = New ODBCResultSet
Set query.Connection = connection
Set result.Query = query

On Error Resume Next

Set CandidatView=db.GetView( "Persons" )    
Set ContactView=dbcontacts.GetView( "(PersonsTestImport)" )

Call connection.ConnectTo("datasource", "username", "password")

If connection.IsConnected Then

Set doc=CandidatView.GetFirstDocument
CandidatView.AutoUpdate = False
While Not ( doc Is Nothing )
            namepers=doc.can_pers(0)
            Set DocContact=ContactView.Getdocumentbykey(consultantref) 

        Set DocContact=ContactView.Getdocumentbykey(consultantref)
        first_name_ref=DocContact.FirstName(0)
        last_name_ref=DocContact.LastName(0)
        email_ref=DocContact.MailAddress(0) 
        query.SQL="UPDATE users SET email_consult_ref='"+email_ref+"', first_name_consult_ref='"+first_name_ref+"',last_name_consult_ref='"+last_name_ref+"' where id_toucan='"+doc.can_doc_ID(0)+"'"

     result.Execute

    If result.IsResultSetAvailable Then

        Do
            result.NextRow
        Loop Until result.IsEndOfData   
    End If

    Set doc = CandidatView.GetNextDocument( doc )
Wend
End If
result.Close(DB_CLOSE)
connection.Disconnect

End Sub
```